# Error al contruir o ejecutar mi app con firebase flutter

Tags: flutter

Tengo este problema al querer construir mi `app` en vsCode usando `Flutter` el comando que ejercito es :

```
flutter build apk
```

El error solo pasa cuando agrego todo el contenido para usar `firebase` en `flutter`

> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> *What went wrong:
>
> Execution failed for task ':app:mapReleaseSourceSetPaths'.
>
> Error while evaluating property 'extraGeneratedResDir' of task:app:mapReleaseSourceSetPaths' > Failed to calculate the value of task :app: mapReleaseSourceSetPaths' property 'extraGeneratedResDir'. > Querying the mapped value of provider (java.util.Set) before task :app:processReleaseGoogleServices ompleted is not supported
>
> Try:
>
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
>
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
>
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
>
> - Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
>
> BUILD FAILED in 10m
>
> Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease
>
> 677,8s
>
> Gradle task assembleRelease failed with exit code 1

Comment: Pulsa en [edit] y muestra tu _build.gradle_. No olvides revisar la versión de _com.google.gms.google-services_.